# Modifying list slice passed into a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to pass a slice of a list into a function and modify the list via the slice?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
def foo(a_list):
  a_list[0]='abc'

x=[1,2,3,4]
foo(x[0:2])
```

I want x to now be x=['abc',2,3,4]

Comment: `x[0,2]` will raise an error.  Do you mean `x[0:2]`?

Comment: I seriously doubt it, given that slicing gives you a new list. If you need to have things update, do `x[0:2] = foo(x[0:2])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  A "list slice" in the sense you describe is nothing but a new list.  When you do `x[0:2]`, the resulting list does not "know" that it was created as a slice of another list.  It's just a new list.

What you could do is pass in the slice object itself, separately from the list:

```
def foo(a_list, a_slice):
  a_list[a_slice]='abc'

>>> foo(x, slice(0, 2))
>>> x
['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 4]
```

Comment: If a list slice is a new list how come I can modify a list by modifying its slice? For example, `l = [1, 2, 3]; l[0] = 100` will turn the first element of the list into 100.

Comment: @Heisenberg: You should ask a separate question if you have a separate question.

Comment: I asked a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61580214/if-python-slice-copy-the-reference-why-cant-i-use-it-to-modify-the-original-li

Answer (score 3):

No!  Slices create copies of lists (see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)).  You can do this:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x[1:3] = [7, 8, 9]
>>> X
[1, 7, 8, 9, 4]
```

But, when you get a new list from a slicing operation, it's a copy, and thus changes to it won't affect the original:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> y = x[1:3]
>>> y[0] = 5
>>> y
[5, 3]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def foo(a_list):
  a_list[0]='abc'
  return a_list

x=[1,2,3,4]
foo(x) #it returns x=['abc',2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumably you're trying to pass in `x[0:2]`, rather than `x[0,2]`, but the reason it doesn't work is because when you create a slice you are creating a subarray copy of `x`.

You are not operating on the same instance of that array, what you are doing is passing an entirely new array. Passing in 'x' alone would work, but passing in `x[0:2]` would not unless you specifically wrote it as `x[0:2] = foo(x[0:2])` and had foo() return `a_list`.

Answer (score 2):

As brenns10 explained, slices create a copy (even in python 3.0) of your origional data.

You could do something like the following:

```
def foo(x):
  x[0] = 'abc'
  return x

x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
x[0:2] = foo(x[0:2])  # x = ['abc', 1, 2, 3]
```

While this gives you the desired outcome, it doesn't exactly work as you would want. This could be problematic if needing to perform large slices as you'd have to perform a lot of copying.