# If Python slice copy the reference, why can't I use it to modify the original list?

Tags: python, list, reference

I know that [Slicing lists does not generate copies of the objects in the list; it just copies the references to them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131538/slicing-a-list-in-python-without-generating-a-copy)

But if that's the case, then why doesn't this work?

```
l = [1, 2, 3]

# Attempting to modify the element at index 1
l[0:2][-1] = 10

# but the attempt fails. The original list is unchanged
l
> [1, 2, 3]
```

Shouldn't `l[0:2][-1]` point to the element at index 1 of the original list?

Comment: You can't modify the element itself; it's immutable. Assigning to an element of a list replaces one reference with another.

Comment: Also, there is a differnce between "copying the list"  (shallow copy) and "copying the objects of the list" (deep copy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that slicing doesn't copy the items in the list.  However, it does create a new list object.

Your comment suggests a misunderstanding:

```
# Attempting to modify the element at index 1
l[0:2][-1] = 10
```

This is not a modification of the *element*, it's a modification of the *list*.  In other words it is really "change the list so that index 1 now points to the number 10".  Since your slice created a new list, you are just changing that new list to point at some other object.

In your comment to oldrinb's answer, you said:

> Why are `l[0:1]` and `l[0:1][0]` different? Shouldn't they both refer to the same object, i.e. the first item of `l`?

Aside from the fact that `l[0:1]` is a list while `l[0:1][0]` is a single element, there is again the same misunderstanding here.  Suppose that `some_list` is a list and the object at index `ix` is `obj`.  This:

```
some_list[ix] = blah
```

. . . is an operation on `some_list`.  The object `obj` is not involved.  This can be confusing because it means `some_list[ix]` has slightly different semantics depending on which side of the assignment it is on.  If you do

```
blah = some_list[ix] + 2
```

. . .then you are indeed operating on the object inside the list (i.e., it is the same as `obj + 2`).  But when the indexing operation is on the left of the assignment, it no longer involves the contained object at all, only the list itself.

When you assign to a list index you are modifying the *list*, not the object inside it.  So in your example `l[0]` is the same as `l[0:2][0]`, but that doesn't matter; because your indexing is an assignment target, it's modifying the list and doesn't care what object was in there already.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it gets at the heart of my misunderstanding. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Slicing a `list` returns a *new* shallowly-copied `list` object. While you are correct that it does not deep-copy the original list's items, the result is a brand new `list` distinct from the original.

See the [Python 3 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

> All slice operations return a new list containing the requested elements. This means that the following slice returns a shallow copy of the list:
>
> ```
> >>> squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
> >>> squares[:]
> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
> ```

Consider

```
>>> squares[:] is squares
False
```

Comment: Even though the slice is a new list, it still contains the reference to the old objects. (That's what I think "shallow copy" means.) That makes sense, given that `l = [1,2,3]; l[0:1] = [10]` does modify the list.

However, `l[0:1][0] = [10]` does not modify the list. Why are `l[0:1]` and `l[0:1][0]` different? Shouldn't they both refer to the same object, i.e. the first item of `l`?

Comment: @Heisenberg `l[0:1] = [10]` is not constructing a new `list` from a `slice`--it is assigning to the existing `list` using a `slice`. on the other hand, `l[0:1][0] = 10` is *first* constructing a new `list` using a `slice` and *then* assigning to its first element using an simple index (`0`).

Comment: the distinction is that `l[0:1] = [10]` is equivalent to `l.__setitem__(slice(0, 1), [10])` whereas `l[0:1][0] = 10` is akin to `l.__getitem__(slice(0, 1)).__setitem__(0, 10)`

Comment: in the first instance, you are calling `__setitem__` on `l` and thus mutating the original list; in the second, however, you are mutating the newly-created `list` from `l.__getitem__`. to more clearly see what is happening, consider introducing an intermediate variable like so: `l2 = l[0:1]; l2[0] = 10`. inspecting `l2` afterward you will notice `l2 == [10]` with `l` is unchanged

Comment: @Heisenberg: I added an answer that may clarify matters.  The main point is that when you assign to a list index you are not affecting the object in the list; you are only modifying the list itself (so you are modifying the new list that your slice created).

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of explaining it better, assume you had written

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
k = l[0:2]
k[-1] = 10
```

I hope you can agree that this is equivalent.

Now let's break down the individual statements:

#### `l = [1, 2, 3]`

This creates the following objects and references:

```
id  object
--  --------
0   <int 1>
1   <int 2>
2   <int 3>
3   <list A>
```

```
name  →  id
----     --
l     →  3
l[0]  →  0
l[1]  →  1
l[2]  →  2
```

#### `k = l[0:2]`

This creates a new list `<list B>` containing copies of the references contained in `l`:

```
id  object
--  --------
0   <int 1>
1   <int 2>
2   <int 3>
3   <list A>
4   <list B>
```

```
name  →  id
----     --
l     →  3
l[0]  →  0
l[1]  →  1
l[2]  →  2
k     →  4
k[0]  →  0  (copy of l[0])
k[1]  →  1  (copy of l[1])
```

#### `k[-1] = 10`

First, index −1 resolves to index 1 (because `k` has length 2), so this is equivalent to `k[1] = 10`. This assignment means that the objects and references are updated as such:

```
id  object
--  --------
0   <int 1>
1   <int 2>
2   <int 3>
3   <list A>
4   <list B>
5   <int 10>
```

```
name  →  id
----     --
l     →  3
l[0]  →  0
l[1]  →  1
l[2]  →  2
k     →  4
k[0]  →  0
k[1]  →  5
```

Note how `l` and `l[0]` to `l[2]` are not affected by this. QED.