# How does passing a list as an argument work in Python3?

Tags: python, list, recursion, memory-management, bubble-sort

I was trying to code Bubble Sort using recursion, when I ran into this problem.

```
def bubble_sort_recur(a):
    print(a)
    if len(a)==1:
        return
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[i] > a[i+1] :
            a[i]=a[i]^a[i+1] # swap using XOR
            a[i+1]=a[i]^a[i+1]
            a[i]=a[i]^a[i+1]
    print(a) # shows the changes made in the current call
    bubble_sort_recur(a[:-1])

b=[1,6,1,66,3,32,21,33,1] # initial list
bubble_sort_recur(b) # function call
```

I think that python uses pass by Object reference for objects(lists). The output of the recursion also was expected, and as follows:

```
[1, 6, 1, 66, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1]
[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1, 66] # 66 bubbles up
[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 21, 32, 1, 33]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 21, 32, 1]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 21, 1, 32]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 21, 1]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 21]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 1]
[1, 1, 3, 1, 6]
[1, 1, 3, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
[1]
```

One can see that the third '1' bubbles down to the 2nd index as expected.
But when I do `print(b)`  I get `[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1, 66]` which is neither the **sorted list** nor the **original list**(`b=[1,6,1,66,3,32,21,33,1]`).
Could you please explain the reason for getting such a **mixed** behaviour?
Something I tried to explore the working is as follows:

```
def func(a):
    a[0]='only one altered'
def func2(b):
    a=['this','is', 'completely', 'new']
a=[1,'initial',2, 'array']
func(a) # this changes the list
print(a)
func2(a) # this does not change the list 'a' , in any way.
print(a)
```

```
>> ['only one altered', 'initial', 2, 'array']
   ['only one altered', 'initial', 2, 'array']
```

I notice that , the *actual* list gets altered when I change the value of the list inside of the function by **using the index**. Otherwise the list remains unaffected.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You pass a reference to the list, but in the recursive call `bubble_sort_recur(a[:-1])` you create a slice, which is a partial (shallow) copy.

Comment: Why are you using the xor hack to swap? `a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]` works fine.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61580339/3080723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not return a value and relies on the list being mutable for it to be changed in place. However, you then call recursion with a slice of the the current list, which makes a copy (and therefore a new list), so the list `b` is no longer being referenced.

You can verify this by adding a `print(b)` line before recursion.

```
def bubble_sort_recur(a):
    print(a)
    if len(a)==1:
        return
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if a[i] > a[i+1] :
            a[i]=a[i]^a[i+1] # swap using XOR
            a[i+1]=a[i]^a[i+1]
            a[i]=a[i]^a[i+1]
    print(a) # shows the changes made in the current call
    print(b)
    print()
    bubble_sort_recur(a[:-1])

b=[1,6,1,66,3,32,21,33,1] # initial list
bubble_sort_recur(b) # function call
```

Output

```
[1, 6, 1, 66, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1]
[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1, 66]
[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1, 66] # first call changed b

[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 21, 32, 1, 33]
[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1, 66] # none of the recursions changed b

[1, 1, 3, 6, 21, 32, 1]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 21, 1, 32]
[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1, 66]

[1, 1, 3, 6, 21, 1]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 21]
[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1, 66]

[1, 1, 3, 6, 1]
[1, 1, 3, 1, 6]
[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1, 66]

[1, 1, 3, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1, 66]

[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1, 66]

[1, 1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1, 66]

[1]
```

One solution would be to include a return call.

```
def bubble_sort_recur(a):
    if len(a) > 1:
        for i in range(len(a)-1):
            if a[i] > a[i+1] :
                a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i] # more pythonic syntax
                # or
                # a[i:i+2] = a[i+1:i-1:-1]
                # or your original code
                # a[i]=a[i]^a[i+1] # swap using XOR
                # a[i+1]=a[i]^a[i+1]
                # a[i]=a[i]^a[i+1]
        print(a)
        a[:-1] = bubble_sort_recur(a[:-1]) # catch the result of recursion
    return a

b = [1,6,1,66,3,32,21,33,1] # initial list
b = bubble_sort_recur(b) # function call
```

```
[1, 1, 6, 3, 32, 21, 33, 1, 66]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 21, 32, 1, 33]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 21, 1, 32]
[1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 21]
[1, 1, 3, 1, 6]
[1, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1]

>>> print(b)
[1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 21, 32, 33, 66]
```

Answer (score 0):

`a[:-1]` creates a new list, and you then pass it down